# libaom Cmake(Ubuntu18.04) failed

Tags: cmake

I am compiling aom in Ubuntu18.04 with the code commands are as below:
・libaom

```
mkdir aom-dev  
cd aom-dev  
git clone https://aomedia.googlesource.com/aom  
cmake -DCONFIG_PIC=1 ./aom  
make -j4  
sudo make install
```

error message outputed:

```
Checking C compiler flag support for: -Wextra-semi  
-- Performing Test C_FLAG_SUPPORTED  
-- Performing Test C_FLAG_SUPPORTED - Failed  
Checking C++ compiler flag support for: -Wextra-semi  
-- Performing Test CXX_FLAG_SUPPORTED  
-- Performing Test CXX_FLAG_SUPPORTED - Failed
```

Any hint?

Comment: I think this question needs more context; if you can attach which OS you're working with, the CMake version you're using, and the compiler you're using, it would help narrow the issue you're having. I tried building the repository you shared with the same commands and was successful (I did not execute the install part that should be a non issue)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Here are the details.  
 
OS:ubuntu18.04  
CMake:version 3.10.2  
Compiler:gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

Comment: The message `Performing Test C_FLAG_SUPPORTED - Failed` by itself is NOT an error message. It just means that `-Wextra-semi` is not supported by your compiler. The error message usually contains word "Error". If you configuration (running `cmake`) failed, then such message should be shown to you, and exactly from such message one should start debugging.

Comment: Why can't I upload my CMakeError.log or CMakeOutput.log but only image?

Comment: just put the relevent parts of the file here. or you can discuss this with the maintainers of the project. question: ny particulr reason you're still using gcc 7.5?